# Access denied error in C# while connecting with MySql. I already have full access of Database

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

Hi I am developing and application in which I need to connect to MySQL database on remote server using IP address.

I have used below connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="con" connectionString="Server=***.***.***.***;Port=3306;Database=enview;Uid=myuser;Pwd=****" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

When I try to open connection I am getting below error.

```
Authentication to host '***.***.***.***' for user 'myuser' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'**my IP**' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: The server may not allow remote connections; assuming the credentials are in fact correct.

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud Server allowing remote connection. I tried with PHP it's working fine.

Comment: Does it require HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe sql-server does not allow connections from non-server ip address, or you are prohibited to connect to database with non-server ip address. Check your permissions. May be your permissions were granted to username@localhost not to username@*

Answer (score 1):

Your're not mentioned details about remote server.  If you are using third party remote server containing MySQL database, please ensure that it support remote access.  You can check it on MySQL workbench.  Try to connect same database on MySQL workbench.